# trigger replacement when we change the type value

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, constants

example I have something like this

```
type wallPaper = 'red'
```

I apply this type on 100 variables, then I change my mind and I want another color

```
type wallpaper = 'blue'
```

is there any extension that can trigger auto replacement for all the 100 variables whenever I change the value?

I don't want to use search and replace because it is risky

Currently I am using constant to keep thing consistent, I am using vscode btw

/////////

update: some think this is some kind of x,y problem, here is the explanation what I going to do with it

let say I have something like this

```
type color = "red" | "blue"

const var1: color = "red"
const var2: color = "blue"
const var3: color = "red"
const var4: color = "blue"
const var5: color = "red"
const var6: color = "blue"
const var7: color = "red"
```

imagine there are hundreds or even thousands of them

after that I want to to replace blue with green, so I change my type to

```
type color = "red" | "green"
```

is there any way to replace the existing blue with green on all the related variables?

Comment: Ever heard of the [x-y-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)? What are you really trying to do here? Because it doesn't sound like you're using types in the right way.

Comment: @Olian04 I change my value name frequently(naming struggle), and I also want to limit the value of variable can accept by using union, so if something can auto-replace would be very convenient

Comment: [String enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) might do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is changing the value frequently (as you've described in the comments) then consider using [string enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums).

Here's a [TypeScript Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgBQEoCSAsgIJ4CaUAvFAETLAAmtANFlAMoCiMA8gHIARMpRq0ARgjDBaGAL4YMAYzggAzgBcoANwCGyAIwAuWIhTVTSZADp8xEQG5lqzTv0AmE-CsXvKa9x8Qo7O6lp6yADMXmaoNH42dqQUTiphbsgALDE+8bEBPALCKaGuEQCsOeZ5VraEyeSpLuH6AGxVcZb+gUUhaWX6AOwdvvlJjkA) based on your own example.

```js
enum Color {
  PRIMARY = "red",
  SECONDARY = "blue"
}

const var1: Color = Color.PRIMARY;
const var2: Color = Color.SECONDARY;
const var3: Color = Color.PRIMARY;
const var4: Color = Color.SECONDARY;
const var5: Color = Color.PRIMARY;
const var6: Color = Color.SECONDARY;
const var7: Color = Color.PRIMARY;
```